# how to insert datedropdown value in to database

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is some code i need ur help on, in this code the input form do have a name so that i can store the value of the input form to the database and fetch it to post to another page but those textfield with the script do not recognized, it call them undefined variable but if the textfield it self is apeared without the script it works just by removing the script.but i want to use that plugin by the script n i want u to help me with why do the name variable cant be recognized wn i add that script it works fine w/out it.

```
    <?php $active = "";?>
<?php 
   include 'includes/header.php';
   include 'includes/event_functions.php';


?>
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $event =  get_event_by_id($_GET['id']);

   if ($event != null) {

?>

<div class="container"> 
<div class="clearfix" style="margin-top:20%;"> </div>

   <h1 style="color:#808080;text-align:center;"> Registering new event in afrisol  </h1>
<form method="post" action="updateevent.php" style = "margin-bottom:3%;" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <div class="col-md-12"> 
          <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>
 Event start  date
       </label>
     </div>


     <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="example">
        <input type="date" name="sdate" id="example1">

      </div>
     </div>

   </div>
   <div>
         <!-- date  -->
          <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>
        Event end date
       </label>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="example">
    <input  type="date" class = "form-control" name ="ldate" id="ldate"  /></br></br>
     </div>
</div>
   </div class = "col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>
     Ticket start  date
       </label>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-8">
    <input value= "<?php echo $event->tsdate;?>"  type="Date" class = "form-control" name ="tsdate" /></br></br>
     </div>

   </div>
          <!-- ticket date -->
           <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>
      Ticket end date
       </label>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-8">
    <input value= "<?php echo $event->tldate;?>"  type="Date" class = "form-control" name ="tldate" /></br></br>
     </div>

   </div>
    </div>
    </div>


     <div class="col-md-8">
     <input  type="submit" class = "form-control" name ="submit" value="update" />

     </div>


   <!-- <input value=  type = "text" class = "form-control" name  = "daterange" value="01/01/2015- 01/31/2015" /> -->
     </div>

</form>
  <?php }} ?>
</div>


<?php 
   include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
<script>
      $(function() {
        $("#example1").dateDropdowns();



        // Set all hidden fields to type text for the demo
        $('input[type="hidden"]').attr('type', 'Date').attr('readonly','readoniy');
      });
    </script>
    <link href="js/Easy-Customizable-jQuery-Dropdown-Date-Picker-Plugin/demo/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script  src ="js/Easy-Customizable-jQuery-Dropdown-Date-Picker-Plugin/dist/jquery.date-dropdowns.js"></script>
```

in the other page 'updateevent.php' i have this source code in case...

```
 <?php $active = "";?>
<?php

      include 'includes/header.php';
         include 'includes/util.php'; 
      include 'includes/event_functions.php';

?>
<div style="margin-top:15%;"></div>
<?php   
    if (isset($_POST['id']) ){



         // echo "string";

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
       $ldesc = $_POST['ldesc'];
       $desc = $_POST['desc'];
       $allowComment = $_POST['allowComment'];
       $level= $_POST['level'];
       $eBy = $_POST['by'];
       $country = $_POST['country'];
        $region = $_POST['Region'];
         $Town = $_POST['Town'];
       $kebele = $_POST['Kebele'];
       $Price = $_POST['price'];
       $video = $_POST['video'];
       $catagory = $_POST['catagory'];
       $longtude = $_POST['Longtude'];
       $lattitude = $_POST['lattitude'];
       $sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
       $edate = $_POST['ldate'];
       $tsdate = $_POST['tsdate'];
       $tedate = $_POST['tldate'];

   $update =   update_event( $id , $title, $ldesc, $desc, $allowComment,$level,$eBy,$country,$region,$Town,$kebele,$Price,$video,$catagory,$longtude,$lattitude,$sdate,$edate,$tsdate,$tedate );

      //echo $fName.$mName.$lName.$gender.$email.$phone;
         if ($update > -1) {
            /* header("Location  event_update_success.php?id=".$id);*/
              $event  = get_event_by_id($update);


         echo "<h1 style='color:green;text-align:center;'>you have updated successfully!!</h1>" ;
         echo "<h2 style='color:green;text-align:center;'>with those contents...</h2>"





?>
  <section id="blog" class="container">
        <div class="center">
            <h2> <?php echo $event->title; ?> </h2><hr/>

        </div>




        <div class="blog">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2" style="width:230px;">
                    <div class="blog-item"> 

                            <div class="row">  
                                  <div class="col-md-12"  style="text-align:center;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);border=1px solid;border-radius:10px">

 <h2>About This Event </h2>
         <img src="<?php echo $event->image; ?>" style="height:250px;" class="img-responsive">

           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center" style="border:1px solid #999;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:10px;margin-top:10px;">
         <div class="entry-meta">
        <h3>Event By <b>Afrisol Events </b> </h3>
             <div id="publish_date" style="text-align:left;padding:8px "><div><i class="fa fa-user"></i>  posted by:-<p style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $event->by;?></p> </div></div>

              ***<span style="text-align:left;">
             <h2  style="text-decoration:underline;"> Event Dates</h2>
            <h3 style="color:#333;">Event Start Date:
            </h3><b><?php echo $event->sdate ;?></b>
            <h3 style="color:#333;">Event End Date:
           </h3> <b><?php echo $event->ldate ;?></b>
     <li>Ticket Start Date:
            <b><?php echo $event->tsdate ;?></b></li>
            <li> Ticket End Date:
            <b><?php echo $event->tldate ;?></b></li>-->***
           </span>
            <span style="text-align:left;"><h3>Event For:</h3><b><?php echo $event->level; ?> Membership</b></span>
           <span style="text-align:left;"><h3>Event Catagory : </h3><b><?php echo $event->catagory; ?> </b></span>


            <span style="text-align:left;"><h2 style="text-decoration:underline;">Location</h2>
            <h3>Country:</h3>
            <b><?php echo $event->country ;?></b>
            <h3>Region:</h3>
            <b><?php echo $event->Region ;?></b>
            <h3>City:</h3>
             <b><?php echo $event->Town ;?></b></span>

                           <!-- <span><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><a href="#">56 Likes</a></span> -->
                                    </div></div>

     <span style="text-align:left;"><h3>Map of Event Place</h3></span>
                                <iframe class="actAsDiv" width="100%" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"
 marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;q=<?php echo $event->lattitude?>%2C%20<?php echo $event->longtude?>&amp;aq=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;z=16&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>



</div>


                            </div>
                        </div><!--/.blog-item-->







                    </div><!--/.col-md-8-->
                    <div class="col-md-7" style="margin-left: 10px;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);border=1px solid;border-radius:10px">
      <div style="padding:10px 0px;"><img style="height:300px;width:100%;" src="<?php echo $event->image; ?>"  class="img-responsive"></div>
     <div>  <?php echo $event->desc;?></div>
       <!--<img src="uploads\profile\upload3470digitalManufacturing.jpg" > -->



      </div>

                <aside class="col-md-1" style="width:230px;margin-left: 10px;background-color:#fafafa;height:100%;">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin:5px 0px;">
<div>
 <h2 style="text-align:center;"> AFrisol Events Advertizing Portion </h2>
 <img src="images/at-Afrisol.gif"  class="img-responsive" ></div>

   </div>
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin:5px 0px;">
 <div>
 <h2 style="text-align:center;"> Fasion Design Cotest Adama 2008 </h2>
 <img src="images/news/10X20_youthopia_Adama1.jpg"  class="img-responsive" >
         </div>
   </div>


                </aside>     

            </div><!--/.row-->

         </div><!--/.blog-->

    </section><!--/#blog-->








   <?php   }
           else{

             echo "<h2> Something Must went wrong  </h2>";

           }

       }


      // $passportNum = $_POST['passportNum'];
     //  $level = $_POST['level'];
?>

<?php
 include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: name is mandatory property of element to store data in database.

Comment: @AmitShah Unless he decides to use an AJAX request.

Comment: If you plan to post the values to another page, make sure your inputs are within `<form>` tags

Comment: Yes, in ajax request again you need to create variable name in post data or some other way to pass the data to server side script.

Answer (score 0):

so to answer your question completely, possible things could be.

- add name attribute to element
- add form tag, if you posting data normally
- or add ajax code to submit the form and add it to some variable so that it is available to server side script.

in case needed help please let me know.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: could u give me some instance source code please !!

Comment: i did have made a form and  give a name for the element then i called it by  the name n it says undefined object. but with out the script it works  i mean just textfield input.

Comment: i think now i make it specifically clear and am lookin forward to ur help guys